# How to read JSON content from a file and update using PUT method and HttpURLConnection in JAVA

Tags: api, request, httpurlconnection, put

I'm new in JAVA and want to I read a JSON body contents from a file and update the API using HttpURLConnection.

Any basic code or tips that I may refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You can write json body in a text file like:
{
    "message": "Test",
    "author": "James"
}

Now you can read the file using JSONParser following way:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/james/Desktop/test.txt"));
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
        String msg = (String) jsonObj.get("message");
        String auth = (String) jsonObj.get("author");
        //**Now you can store these values in your class object and proceed with API implementation**
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Add following dependency in pom.xml or download cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/code/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```